# Создание связи многие ко многим

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate

Учусь работать с `Hibernate` и базами данных. Для это взял [эту](https://habrahabr.ru/post/29694/) статью из хабра.

У меня есть класс `Bus` с такими полям:

```
private Long id;
private String number;
private Set drivers = new HashSet();
private Long route_id;
```

И класс `Driver` c таким полями:

```
private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int age;
    private Set busses = new HashSet();
```

Получается, что у нас имеется свзять многие ко многим.

Не очень понимаю как создать эти таблицы в `postgres`. Пробовал так:

```
    autopark=# create table buses(
id serial not null primary key,
number varchar(50) not null,
drivers integer references drivers(id),
route_id integer not null);
```

На что получаю соврешенно спроведливую ошибку:

```
ERROR:  relation "drivers" does not exist
```

Такая же ситуация и с созданием таблицы `drivers`. Как сделать правильно ?

Comment: Вас не смущает первая картинка на хабре с сущностью BusDriver, которая является промежуточной между bus и driver? И второе, хибернейт сам может создать таблицы в БД с параметром `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В реляционных базах данных для связи многие-ко-многим используется таблица связей (join table).
Связанные таким образом таблицы не имеют ссылок друг на друга, но таблица связей ссылается на обе.

```
create table buses (
    id int primary key,
    ...
)

create table drivers (
    id int primary key,
    ...
)

create table buses_drivers (
    bus_id int references buses(id),
    driver_id int references drivers(id),
    primary key (bus_id, driver_id)        
)
```